# error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

I use the Xcode7 release and tried so submit my app for review. After submitting the app for review I got a mail from Apple with the following error:

```
Invalid Bundle - Failed to verify bitcode in 
testapp_main.framework/testapp_main: error: Bundle only contains 
bitcode-marker Testapp.app/Frameworks/testapp_main.framework/testapp_main (armv7) ...
```

I also disabled bitcode in my Build Settings:

[image]

**How do I solve this issue?**

Comment: Which architectures/frameworks/targets/sdk are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Bitcode is enabled in both the framework that I've created myself and the incorporating project. Architectures are arm64, armv7, armv7s. Deployment target is iOS 8.0. SDK is iOS 9 (Xcode 7.0.1).

These are the errors that I get when it fails:
[image]
[image]

**"Solution"**

When trying to validate or submit to iTunes Connect, unchecking *either* "Include app symbols..." *or* "Include bitcode" allows validation to succeed. It's just when both of them are checked that it fails. I wouldn't really consider this a solution though.. You either have to give up receiving crash logs or utilizing app thinking, both of which would be preferably enabled. This is just a temporary workaround until someone else can figure out what is really causing the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue when trying to Archive a flutter project.

The solution I found is to to uncheck **Rebuild from Bitcode**, and click Next **before** the error shows up.